# Can we put condition on REST API

Tags: python, api, rest

I was giving hackerrank test where I got this problem.

Problem was to find number of football matches that are draw. i.e `data[index]['team1goals']==data[index]['team2goals']`

Here is an API you can play with it: https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/football_matches?year=2011&page=1

This is what I tried:

```python
import requests
year = 2011
draw = 0
r = requests.get('https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/football_matches?year='+str(year)+'&page=1').json()
total_pages = r['total_pages']
per_page = r['per_page']

for page in range(1, total_pages+1):
    r = requests.get('https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/football_matches?year='+str(year)+'&page='+str(page)).json()
    try:
        for i in range(0, per_page):
            if int(r['data'][i]['team1goals']) == int(r['data'][i]['team2goals']):
                draw += 1
    except:
        pass
print(draw) #516
```

It is giving me correct answer. Since the data was big, it is facing time complexity which I don't want

Is it possible, Can we modify the REST API with condition like this:

https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/football_matches?year=2011&team1goals==team2goals&page=1

OR

https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/football_matches?year=2011&team1goals-gt-lt&team2goals&page=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the API allows these many calls, you can use a `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` function and iterate through each page parallelly to reduce time. This should work:

```
import requests
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

def loop(page,year,r,per_page):

   r = requests.get('https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/football_matches?year='+str(year)+'&page='+str(page)).json()
   try:
      for i in range(0, per_page):
         if int(r['data'][i]['team1goals']) == int(r['data'][i]['team2goals']):
            increase = 1
         else:
            increase = 0
   except:
      increase = 0
   
   return increase

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
   year = 2011
   draw = []
   r = requests.get('https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/football_matches?year='+str(year)+'&page=1').json()
   total_pages = r['total_pages']
   per_page = r['per_page']
   pages = range(1, total_pages+1)
   pool = Pool()
   f = pool.map(partial(loop,year=year,r=r,per_page=per_page),pages)
   draw += f
   final = 0
   for x in draw:
      x = int(x)
      final += x

   print(final) #516
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `multithreading` and make multiple requests in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it other way.

```
def getNumDraws(year):
counter = 0

for z in range(0, 10):
    # 10 - maximum goals, it's in the description of this task
    link = f"https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/football_matches?year={year}&team1goals={z}&team2goals={z}"
    r = requests.get(link)
    counter = counter + int(r.json()['total'])
return counter
```

Steps:

1. Get `['total']` from link where you add `&team1goals={variable}&team2goals={variable}`
2. Add `['total']` number to your counter.
3. Repeat 10 times. 10 times - because it's from task description that you can assume that there are 10 maximum goals scored.

So you call an api only 10 times